# $\ell_{p^\prime}(\eta)\subseteq\ell_p(\eta)$ when $p^\prime>p$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, jensen-inequality

$\ell_{p^\prime}(\eta)$ and $\ell_p(\eta)$ are weighted Lebesgue sequence spaces and $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\eta_i=1$.

My professor gave the hint that we should use Jensen inequality. I tried to use $\phi(x)=|x|^{\frac{p^\prime}{p}}$, then suppose $\{a_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell_p(\eta)$ I got
$$\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\eta_i|a_i|^{p^\prime}\leq\left|\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\eta_i|a_i|^p\right|^{\frac{p^\prime}{p}}$$
which implies the inclusion in the wrong direction. What is wrong in my proof and what should be the right proof.

Comment: Your application of Jensen’s inequality is wrong. The inequality should be flipped.

Comment: Oh, I see. The inequality direction is wrong. But I still have a question. In my book, it says Jensen's inequality holds if both sides exist. Then I think it's impossible to use Jensen to prove the inclusion because when I use comparison to show the convergence I already assume it exists.

Comment: Both sides do exist. The sum of countably many non-negative elements is always well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\varphi (x) =|x|^{\frac{p}{p'  }}$ is concave continous and $\varphi (0)=0,$
so for any $k\in \mathbb{N} $ we obtain that $$\left(\sum_{j=1}^k \eta_j |a_j|^{p'}\right)^{\frac{p}{p'}} =\varphi \left(\sum_{j=1}^k \eta_j |a_j|^{p'}\right)=\varphi \left(\sum_{j=1}^k \eta_j |a_j|^{p'}+\left(\sum_{j=1}^k \eta_j \right)\cdot 0\right)\geq \sum_{j=1}^k \eta_j \varphi \left(|a_j|^{p'}\right) +0=\sum_{j=1}^k \eta_j |a_j|^{p}$$
and hence
$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^k \eta_j |a_j|^{p'}\right)^{\frac{1}{p'}} \geq \left(\sum_{j=1}^k \eta_j |a_j|^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$
Now by the continuity of power functions we have
$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\eta_j |a_j|^{p'}\right)^{\frac{1}{p'}} =\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sum_{j=1}^k\eta_j |a_j|^{p'}\right)^{\frac{1}{p'}}\geq \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sum_{j=1}^k \eta_j |a_j|^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\eta_j |a_j|^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

Comment: sorry I didn't see your answer before. I wonder why the first inequality in the first line holds. Shouldn't we have phi(x+y)<=phi(x)+phi(y) for concave phi with phi(0)=0?